# Is not receiving email in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I cant receive any email but my if statements says that an email was successfully sent, please help, here is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '****', //email
        'smtp_pass' => '****'  //password
        );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('//email', '//name');
    $this->email->to('//recipient');
    $this->email->subject('This is a test email');
    $this->email->message('Hi, This is a test email. Please advise!');

    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Your email was successfully sent.';
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

btw i tested it by using localhost/email/index.php/email/index

Comment: yes... i am still testing it...

Comment: i would just like to confirm, it has to be live for me to send emails? is their a way I can receive the email without uploading it?

Comment: can you answer so i can tag this as solved...

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25131573/3239572 if you want to send mail from localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mail sending part is correct. No issues with that.

If you are trying this in local you have to edit you mail setting in **php.ini** and **sendmail.ini**.

Or else upload it to live server into new folder name **demo**(Not root). so you can test it easily.